# How to recover from recursive 'chmod -x' on my home folder

Tags: linux, files, executable

I pressed `ENTER` after typing the following stupid command on my home directory:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod -x '{}' ';'
```

What do you advise as a fix for this. My guess is that I can't do anything but do something like:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod og+x '{}' ';'
```

Or may be do some tricky stuff based on extensions (which doesn't seem very pertinent under Linux).

Or may be some of you has an idea or a pointer on how to know which file should be executable under linux and how to detect them to turn them back to executables...

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question so it's clearer what you're wanting. I'm thinking you're interested in finding executables and putting them back the way they were before your `find` command but I'm not sure. If that's the case, you're probably in for a very manual process. The only thing you can really programmatically determine is whether something is an ELF binary, but that doesn't mean you necessarily want it to be executable (a shared object, for instance).

Comment: At least you didn't `chmod -x` the directories!

Comment: @Keith that would be much easier to fix. There's no ambiguity, and if `find` can't descend into them, just loop until it reaches the deepest levels.

Comment: Is this actually causing you any problems?

Comment: Well, I pressed Ctrl-C quite fastn but I already found some `.so` files that are not executable anymore. So I suppose this will be an issue for me quite soon...

Comment: Just to give you some feedback and thank you all: As pressed Ctrl-C quite fast after having having validated my command, I ran that one `find . -type f > f.txt` over my whole home and tracked the very first `.so` file that was still executable, which led to something like 27946 files. And, as I am a very lucky guy, only the first 109 of the list where not in a safe place. So, I'm gonna run the script bellow over those few files, or even check them manually. Thanks again to both of you for your time and concern. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a script that I wrote a while back to fix permissions on files copied from a FAT system. Won't work if the file names contain newlines (although if someone wants to fix it so that it does, feel free):

```
#!/bin/sh

[ $# != 0 ] && dir="$1" || dir=.

[ -d "$dir" ] || { echo "usage: $0 [dir]"; exit 1; }

cat <<- EOF
  Will recursively alter permissions under directory '$dir'.
  Consider backing up permissions with 'getfacl -R $dir' first.
  Continue? [Y/n]"
EOF

read reply
[ "$reply" = Y ] || exit 0

echo "Changing all directories to mode 755..."
find "$dir" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

# simplest way for now is just to make all files non executable, then fix ones which should be
echo "Changing all files to mode 644..."
find "$dir" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +

# use a temp file instead of a variable since the shell will strip nulls from the string
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

# screwed if filename contains a newline - fixable with a better sed script
echo "Using magic to find executables..."
find $dir -type f -exec file -hN0 -e apptype -e cdf -e compress -e elf -e tar -e tokens {} + |
  sed -n '/\x0.*executable/p' >"$tmpfile"

# ELF binaries
echo "\nSetting ELF executables to mode 755...\n"
sed '/\x0.*ELF/!d; s/\x0.*$//' "$tmpfile" | xargs -rd '\n' chmod -c 755

scripts=$(sed '/\x0.*text/!d; s/\x0.*$//' "$tmpfile")

IFS="
"

# only make scripts executable if they have a shebang
echo "\nSetting scripts with a shebang to mode 755...\n"
for file in $scripts
do
  head "$file" | grep -q '^#!' && chmod -c 755 "$file"
done

rm "$tmpfile"
```

Comment: @Gauthier, I do have to say that my shell scripting has came on a bit since I originally wrote this, so there are a couple of dodgy bits there. I will need to take some time to revisit it, but it should work ok for most cases on Linux, certainly for all sane executable names.

Comment: @Gauthier, a few minor changes, but its late for me so anything more substantial will have to wait.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. But don't be in a hurry, since, as mentioned in a comment above, I reduced my scope to 109 files. Which can be safely managed by hand. Anyway, since this script would be very useful, for many purposes (not only related to my current issue), that would be great from you if you can provide a renewed one. Have a good rest ;)

Comment: Your script worked like a charm on the main issued directory I had. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to leave it as it is and discover missing executable permissions when you need the files.

However, you can be smarter than that. First of all, if you use `.sh` extensions on shell scripts, you can chmod them with find. Similar for perl and python scripts. Additionally, you could loop through the files and look for the `#!` in the first line, if it exists, make the file executable.

And last, compiled binaries can be detected with `file`. For instance:

```
file clock_test
clock_test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 .......
```

Which you can test with `| grep ELF`. So you could just write a script that tests all these options and fix the permissions if it guesses it should be executable.

Comment: OK, tahnks. Personally, I always use `.sh` on my custom scripts, but the big issue is that I'm working on a cluster, for which I do not have root access (which is not that bad, for someone who run dangerous recursive commands ;). So, all my tools are installed in my home and should be damaged after that.

Comment: Checking with `file` should fix all binaries, no damage done.

Comment: OK, good point. And regarding scripts, mine can be found with '.sh', even if I forget, some time to time, to make them start with a shebang. And most of the scripts provided with the tools I installed should have shebangs. So, I think that most of the pain can be solved like suggested by you and `Graeme`'s script. With a slight modification to handle my .sh scripts with missing shebangs.

Comment: @GauthierBoaglio if they don't have shebangs, then they can only be executed by calling `sh` on them directly, in which case it doesn't matter if they're executable or not. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, not exactly because I run bash scripts from bash shells: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9945113/1715716

Comment: Well whaddayaknow. You CAN run a script without a shebang and without specifying an interpreter! I never knew.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we used to fix this in the old days (c. 1984)!

Now, in your case it was from your home directory, which makes it less likely this particular solution will help you, but, as others may run across this request AND will have done so from `/`, `/usr`, or another high-level directory, it is worth considering.

1. Go to another server running the same OS. If you don't have one, instantiate it up on Amazon Web Services (AWS). It will likely qualify as a free instance considering how very little work it will take to get a reference listing of the affected directory tree.
2. on a clean copy of the OS, `ls -lR > /tmp/clean` from the folder in which you started your recursive file munging
3. do the same from your munged folder on the computer requiring the fix
4. you will likely want to use `cut` to remove the dates and sizes, as they may differ do to minor/major version differences.
5. `diff` the two files saving the output
6. use the output to find the files where the permissions don't match.

Another approach would be to read the output from the clean OS's listing and use it to apply to correct permissions on your affected OS.

I hope this comes in handy to someone out there.

Comment: That's an interesting general information / approach, that gives me the idea to backup my files permissions and more generally, all the possible information concerning my files, to be able to restore some of them after some mistaken operation. So this can be very helpful, in my case as well. Thanks a lot Hugo!

Comment: If I have time, and I really should find some, to write such a backup/recovery script, I'll share it. Or, more probably, googling a bit should avoid to reinvent the wheel. Cheers.